# Use ngFor Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a problem con ngFor because I try use 'article' or 'div'

Error:

```
 message: 'Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.'



 message: 'Property binding ngForFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".'


<section class='mycontainer'>
  <article *ngFor="let numberStep for steps; let i = index" 
    [ngClass]="article + i">
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='circle'></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

How do I use this *ngFor with a separator ?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
*ngFor="let numberStep of steps; let i = index;"
```

and you also need to ensure you have imported CommonModule into the module of that component, article

Comment: Actually [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) is a native html 5 tag.. there is no angular component here

Comment: what i meant is that, whatever component is using the <article> element needs to have Commonmodule imported into its parent module

Answer (score 1):

Use ngFor="let numberStep of steps; let i = index" or ngFor="let numberStep in steps; let i = index"

You are doing mistake by using for inside *ngFor directive